# Reading lambda expressions from keyboard in Common Lisp

Tags: input, lambda, common-lisp

I want to be able to read a lambda expression from the keyboard. For example, if a function square has already been DEFUNed I can enter the symbol name:

```
(defun square (x) (* x x))
```

so that when the following is evaluated:

```
(funcall (read) 2)
```

the user can type `square` and the result is 4. But if the user types

```
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

the result is an error, for example in Macintosh Common Lisp,

> Error: (LAMBDA (X) (* X X)) can't be FUNCALLed or APPLYed

Is there an easy way to do this I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER 8 > (defun read-function (&optional (stream *standard-input*))
              (let ((f (read stream)))
                (cond (; function object
                       (functionp f) f)
                      (; symbol naming a function
                       (symbolp f) (symbol-function f))
                      (; (function f)
                       (and (consp f)
                            (eq (first f) 'function))
                       (eval f))
                      (; (lambda ...)
                       (and (consp f)
                            (eq (first f) 'lambda))
                       (eval f)))))
READ-FUNCTION
```

Examples:

```
CL-USER 9 > (read-function)
#.#'+
#<Function + 40F0044AD4>

CL-USER 10 > (read-function)
+
#<Function + 40F0044AD4>

CL-USER 11 > (read-function)
#'+
#<Function + 40F0044AD4>

CL-USER 12 > (read-function)
(lambda (a b) (+ a b))
#<anonymous interpreted function 4060000C8C>
```

Answer (score 9):

[`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) returns a [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm) which has to be *evaluated* before it can be [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm)ed.

This can be accomplished using [read-time evaluation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhf.htm):

```
(funcall (read) 2)
#.(lambda (x) (* x x))
==> 4
```

However, generally speaking, this is a security hole (you are evaluating user-supplied code - what if they typed `#.(start-nuclear-war)`?) so a cautious engineer will bind [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) to `nil` when reading input they have no control over.

Thus it is much better to use [`coerce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm) explicitly:

```
(funcall (coerce (let ((*read-eval* nil)) (read)) 'function) 2)
1+
==> 3
(funcall (coerce (let ((*read-eval* nil)) (read)) 'function) 2)
(lambda (x) (* x x))
==> 4
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using `read`, in general you would need to evaluate the returned forms to obtain meaningful values. But in your particular case, you can use [`COERCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm). For example, from a REPL:

```
CL-USER> (coerce '+ 'function)
#<FUNCTION +>
```

The above finds the function to which the symbol `+` is [*fbound*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fbound.htm).

```
CL-USER> (coerce '(lambda (x) (* x x)) 'function)
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {53F2BF2B}>
```

The above takes a [*lambda expression*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lambda_expression) and turn it into a function object.

Answer (score 3):

You get that error because `READ` returns just the **list** `(LAMBDA (X) (* x x))`, it does not evaluate it to a function. To do that, you would need to write:

```
(funcall (eval (read)) 2)
```

Note though that in that case, just writing `square` doesn't work anymore, the user would now need to enter `#'square`.